# PostgreSQL connection pool handling via vb.net

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, connection-pooling, connection

For Example,

In my `vb.net` application i have created two forms called `FormA` and `FormB`.When completes the `FormA` 's load `dbMonitor` shows `Connection is returned to pool. Pool has 4 connection(s)` and in the case of `Formb` `dbMonitor` shows `Connection is returned to pool. Pool has 5 connection(s)`.when i use two form at a time the total connections will be `9`.

- do i need to clear all connection after form's load, if yes which method is safe
- sometimes facing `max connection` problems while using my application via network computers.

*`VB.NET` code to open connection is below*

- i have created a `module` for the connection

  ```
     Imports Devart.Data.PostgreSql
          Module Myconnstrection
          Public Myconnstr As New PgSqlConnection("Server=" & gstrServerName & ";Port=" & gstrPort & ";Database=" & gStrDBName & ";User ID=" & gstrUserName &         ";Password=" & gPassword)
          End Module
  ```

  - i use the `MyConnstr` in my forms load or where ever a connection to the database is needed

> try
>
> Dim adapter As PgSqlDataAdapter = New PgSqlDataAdapter(strSql,
>   MyConnstr) myconnstr.open()
>
> 'Do my job
>
> catch
>
> finally
>
> myconnstr.close()
>
> end try

```
Databsase : PostgreSQL 9.2
OS : windows
```

Comment: instead using your connection as a module variable try to make a public function which should contain `myconn.state=connectionstate.closed` checking if 'closed' then open your connection,and use the this function wherever you want a connection to your `DB`